# Is there a way to print integers normally that are assigned to a pointer array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am creating a program that involves pointers and arrays and I have stumbled upon a problem.
Basically, I created three integers that would get its value from the user's input and later declared them all in an array in order **to change all of their values in one single loop.**

Then I declared a pointer which uses the array inside a loop in order to do that.

Expecting the pointer-array in the loop to print out the data in a normal order, rather, it had printed it backwards.

Mind you, I am a huge beginner to programming C++ and is still learning about pointers.

I have tried changing the index number in

```
pntr = &salary[3];
```

but 3 is the only one that prints out every input in the loop.
0 doesn't do the trick, same goes to 1, 2, 4 and so on and so forth.

I would like to have the new output to have the same syntax (salary1, salary2, salary3) and not reverse it (salary3, salary2, salary1) to have the inputted values be printed out.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int salary1, salary2, salary3;
    cout << "Enter salary for John: ";
    cin >> salary1;
    cout << "Enter salary for Mark: ";
    cin >> salary2;
    cout << "Enter salary for Nathan: ";
    cin >> salary3;
    cout << "Name \t Age \t Position \t Salary" << endl;
    cout << "John \t 16 \t Engineer \t " << salary1 << endl;
    cout << "Mark \t 16 \t Scouter \t " << salary2 << endl;
    cout << "Nathan \t 17 \t Manager \t " << salary3 << endl;
    int salary[3] = {salary1, salary2, salary3};
    int *pntr;
    pntr = &salary[3];
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        cout << "Enter new salary: " << endl;
        cin >> *(pntr + x);
        cout << "Salary 1:" << salary1 << endl;
        cout << "Salary 2:" << salary2 << endl;
        cout << "Salary 3:" << salary3 << endl;
    }
    cout << "Name \t Age \t Position \t Salary" << endl;
    cout << "John \t 16 \t Engineer \t " << salary1 << endl;
    cout << "Mark \t 16 \t Scouter \t " << salary2 << endl;
    cout << "Nathan \t 17 \t Manager \t " << salary3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your initialization of "pntr" causes it to point one past the end of "salary", so "pntr+x" points past the data you want to access.

Comment: Why do you do `cin >> *(pntr + x);` ? Do you want to overwrite salary before printing out the previous ones that the users just entered?

Comment: And Mark is right,, when you do `pntr+x` and dereference it, you're accessing memory out of the bounds of salary array since you already set pntr to point to one past the salary array.

Comment: As stated, `pntr = &salary[3];` immediately puts `pntr` out of bounds of your array. `pntr = salary;` is sufficient, but I wouldn't bother using pointers at all.

Comment: I tried pntr = salary; but it doesn't register the user's input and output new values.

Comment: You also put new salaries into the array, but **never** access the array again, instead only looking at your three unnecessary and unmodified ints.

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change values of `salary1`, `salary2`, `salary3`, you should declare `salary[3]` for `int*`, not `int`!

`int salary[3] = { salary1, salary2, salary3 };`

to

`int* salary[3] = { &salary1, &salary2, &salary3 };`

then your pointer also should be double-pointer like:

`int** pntr = salary;`

finally you should dereference `(pntr + x)` double times because it's now double-pointer:

`cin >> **(pntr + x);`

whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int salary1, salary2, salary3;

    cout << "Enter salary for John: ";
    cin >> salary1;
    cout << "Enter salary for Mark: ";
    cin >> salary2;
    cout << "Enter salary for Nathan: ";
    cin >> salary3;
    cout << "Name \t Age \t Position \t Salary" << endl;
    cout << "John \t 16 \t Engineer \t " << salary1 << endl;
    cout << "Mark \t 16 \t Scouter \t " << salary2 << endl;
    cout << "Nathan \t 17 \t Manager \t " << salary3 << endl;

    int* salary[3] = { &salary1, &salary2, &salary3 };
    int** pntr = salary;

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        cout << "Enter new salary: " << endl;
        cin >> **(pntr + x);
        cout << "Salary 1:" << salary1 << endl;
        cout << "Salary 2:" << salary2 << endl;
        cout << "Salary 3:" << salary3 << endl;
    }

    cout << "Name \t Age \t Position \t Salary" << endl;
    cout << "John \t 16 \t Engineer \t " << salary1 << endl;
    cout << "Mark \t 16 \t Scouter \t " << salary2 << endl;
    cout << "Nathan \t 17 \t Manager \t " << salary3 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

you might still have some question about the line

`int** pntr = salary;`

`pntr` is `int**` type and `salary` is `int*[3]` type,

array's address represents the array's first element's address,

so it's same with:

`int** pntr = &salary[0];`

you can easily find it same

just execute whole code with above two different initialization

you may write `int** pntr = &salary[3];` if you don't have clear understanding

`&salary[3]` is representing `salary[3]`'s address,

and `salary[3]` is just an `int*` value, not an array "type"

it represents the array `salary`'s third element's address, remember it

only in initialization index represents the size of array, after initialization index represents value

Comment: This was what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: Why not just store all three values in an array in the first place instead of having `salary1`, `salary2`, `salary3` as three separate variables and then constructing an array of pointers to those variables?

Comment: I was trying to find if it was possible to have three separate values delcared and used later in an array so I declared them that way.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate issue is two-fold. You initialize your pointer and immediately point it out of the array. If you have an array of capacity 3, your indices are as follows:

```
 --- --- ---
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
 --- --- ---
```

Index 3 is not in your array, so your pointer is pointing outside of it. Change your initialization to: `int* pntr = salary;`.

Then, your other issue is that while you put the new salaries into the array, you never access the array again. Instead, you look at your three `int` variables again, which you never modified. The variables are also not needed for this exercise at all.

Here is a cut-down version of your code that fixes the immediate issue.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int salary1, salary2, salary3;

  std::cout << "Enter salary for John: ";
  std::cin >> salary1;
  std::cout << "Enter salary for Mark: ";
  std::cin >> salary2;
  std::cout << "Enter salary for Nathan: ";
  std::cin >> salary3;
  std::cout << "Name \t Age \t Position \t Salary" << '\n';
  std::cout << "John \t 16 \t Engineer \t " << salary1 << '\n';
  std::cout << "Mark \t 16 \t Scouter \t " << salary2 << '\n';
  std::cout << "Nathan \t 17 \t Manager \t " << salary3 << '\n';

  int salary[3] = {salary1, salary2, salary3};
  int *pntr = salary;  // CHANGED

  // CHANGE: Print the array
  for (auto i : salary) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }

  for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    std::cout << "Enter new salary: ";
    std::cin >> *(pntr + x);
    std::cout << "Salary " << x + 1 << ": " << salary[x]
              << '\n';  // CHANGED: Access the array
  }

  // CHANGE: Print the array
  for (auto i : salary) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It seems odd that you would have an array just for salaries. Here is a fresh take on your program that utilizes some C++ concepts that you likely haven't seen yet, but I hope you'll be able to appreciate how much simpler it makes your code. Note that I wouldn't call this code best practices by a long shot, but I think it serves its purpose of demonstrating some new principles.

The biggest design change is that instead of an array of just salaries, we have an array of people, and we can change their salaries if we need to.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;
  std::string title;
  int salary;
};

void print_table(const std::vector<Person>& emp) {
  std::size_t maxNameLength = 0;
  std::size_t maxTitleLength = 0;
  for (auto i : emp) {
    if (i.name.length() > maxNameLength) maxNameLength = i.name.length();
    if (i.title.length() > maxTitleLength) maxTitleLength = i.title.length();
  }

  std::cout << std::setw(maxNameLength + 1) << "Name"
            << "|Age|" << std::setw(maxTitleLength + 1) << "Title"
            << "|Salary\n";
  for (auto i : emp) {
    std::cout << std::setw(maxNameLength + 1) << i.name << "|" << std::setw(3)
              << i.age << "|" << std::setw(maxTitleLength + 1) << i.title << "|"
              << std::setw(6) << i.salary << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Person> employees{{"John", 16, "Engineer", 0},
                                {"Mark", 16, "Scouter", 0},
                                {"Nathan", 17, "Manager", 0}};

  for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    std::cout << "Enter new salary for " << employees[x].name << ": ";
    std::cin >> employees[x].salary;
  }

  print_table(employees);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter new salary for John: 34
Enter new salary for Mark: 45
Enter new salary for Nathan: 56
   Name|Age|    Title|Salary
   John| 16| Engineer|    34
   Mark| 16|  Scouter|    45
 Nathan| 17|  Manager|    56
```

Comment: I haven't thought about it this way, this gave me new insights towards what I'm learning. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int salary1, salary2, salary3;

    cout << "Enter salary for John: ";
    cin >> salary1;
    cout << "Enter salary for Mark: ";
    cin >> salary2;
    cout << "Enter salary for Nathan: ";
    cin >> salary3;
    cout << "Name \t Age \t Position \t Salary" << endl;
    cout << "John \t 16 \t Engineer \t " << salary1 << endl;
    cout << "Mark \t 16 \t Scouter \t " << salary2 << endl;
    cout << "Nathan \t 17 \t Manager \t " << salary3 << endl;

    int salary[3] = {salary1, salary2, salary3};

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      cout << "Enter new salary: " << endl;
      cin >> * (salary + x);
      cout << "Salary " << x << ": " << * (salary + x) << endl;
    }

    cout << "Name \t Age \t Position \t Salary" << endl;
    cout << "John \t 16 \t Engineer \t " << salary[0] << endl;
    cout << "Mark \t 16 \t Scouter \t " << salary[1] << endl;
    cout << "Nathan \t 17 \t Manager \t " << salary[2] << endl;
}
```

Perhaps you want something like this in the end ?

Things to note :

- arrays decay to pointer so you don 't need the extra pointer
- salary1, salary2, salary3 will not be overwritten as you probably expected as they are never touched.The memory in the salary array will be overwritten when you do `cin >> *(salary+ x);`
- So in the end you want to print what is in the array and not the salary1, 2, 3 variables (probably)

Comment: I haven't really grasped the whole concepts of pointers but this was helpful into my learning journey. Thank you!